# rules() function in Laravel Request doesn't create unique slugs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make simple unique slugs. The slugs are saved correctly in database, so the function is working. I have problems with making them unique.

I have this rule in TagCreateRequest.php

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'tag' => 'required|min:3',
        'tag_slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:tag,tag_slug,'
    ];

    $rule = 'unique:tag';

    $segments = $this->segments();
    $id = intval(end($segments));
    if ($id != 0) {  
         $rule .= ',tag_slug,' . $id;
    }
    $rules['tag_slug'][] = $rule;
        return $rules;      
}
```

and this in my store function in the controller

```
  public function store(TagCreateRequest $request)
  {

        $tag = new Tag();
        foreach (array_keys($this->fields) as $field) {             
            $tag->$field = $request->get($field);               
        }

        $tag->save();       
        return redirect()->route('tags');
  }
```

The error is about trying to add duplicate value

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'unique slug' for key 'tags_tag_unique'

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Is it column `tag_slug` or column `slug` in `tag` table  ?

Comment: It's `tag_slug`

Comment: I am talking about `unique:tag,slug` , just asking that its not typo ?

Comment: then it should be `unique:tag(table name) ,tag_slug (field name)`

Comment: Yes, @user2486, it was typo. Thanks but still same erro.

Comment: can you please try by removing duplicate entries (if any) and then run test again

Comment: But maybe the whole function is wrong because how will know to add `slug-1`, `slug-2` etc on duplicates. Is this something that Laravel handles by default?

Comment: May be there is something wrong after defining `$rules` , remove all this and try you get duplication error even for update, then you can add other code to exclude updating id

Comment: @Peter : if `unique:tag,slug` this is typo please update your question

Comment: @user2486, updated, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the id field magically. ID must be the same route parameter used in your route.

If you use id parameter like as `Route::put('post/{id}/update')` then you can magically access the id parameter inside your form request. Otherwise, if you call the parameter of {post} `Route::put('post/{post}/update')`, in your form request you must be call `$this->post` instead of `$this->id`, ok?

Please try it:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'tag' => 'required|min:3'
    ];

    $slugRule = 'required|alpha_dash|unique:tag_slug';

    if (! empty($this->id)) {
        $slugRule = 'required|alpha_dash|unique:tag_slug,'.$this->id;
    }

    $rules['tag_slug'] = $slugRule;

    return $rules;
}
```

This FormRequest will work fine on the store() and update() methods if you inject him in both methods.

See it:

```
// Your store route
Route::post('/post/store', ['as' => 'post.store', 'uses' => 'YourController@store']);

// YourController store method
public function store(NameSpaced\FormRequest $request)
{
   // ...     
}

// Your update route
Route::post('/post/{id}/update', ['as' => 'post.update', 'uses' => 'YourController@store']);

// YourController update method
public function update(NameSpaced\FormRequest $request)
{
    // ...     
}
```

Comment: But this is my store function eg. creating tags, not update

Comment: @peter : if you are getting `id` this answer would work for you

Comment: @Peter this function will verify if ID attribute exists. When id is present, the function will work to validate a update entry instead create.

Comment: @peter When your route does not have an ID it means that you are trying to create a new record. When your route has an ID, it means that you are updating a record.

Comment: @MauricioRodrigues, that's what I'm saying - I'm creating, not updating. Therefore I don't have `ID`

Comment: @Peter So. Everything is alright. Your route will now look similar to Route :: post ('/ post / new', ['uses' => 'YourController @ store']). In this case the form request will not check if the record exists by ignoring its own ID. It will simply check if the record exists (not entering the IF)

Comment: Yes, I understand that.

Comment: When you are editing a record, your form's action will probably be: / post / id / update. In this case the ID will exist and the form request will validate the IF.

Comment: That it correct. But I still don't see how to handle this on `create`

Comment: @Peter Injecting the FormRequest on the store() method too

Answer (score 0):

```
$rules = [
    'tag' => 'required|min:3',
    'tag_slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:[table name],[column name]'
];
```

Try this the first is table name and the second is column name that you wanted to unique, write without adding square braces. or you just pass table name like this,

```
$rules = [
    'tag' => 'required|min:3',
    'tag_slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:[table name]'
];
```

laravel auto checks for the column.
I hope it helps.

Comment: can you please share ss after change

Comment: How is adding `slug-1`, `slug-2` etc on duplicates handles in Laravel. Is this something that Laravel handles by default?

Comment: laravel provides unique rule, that can only handle this, [table name] put your table name without adding braces there

Comment: Check this manual you better understand what is going on wrong,
[link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)

Comment: If you satisfied with my answer and it helps you, then do not forget to mark my answer as right answer.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you automatically generate a new slug whenever you are creating a tag. I got myself in same issues that you have listed here, so i decided on automatically generating whenever i am creating a new item. I used [laravel-sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable). It automatically generates unique slugs.

As per your question, i have defined a unique slug rule in one of my demo apps like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'  => 'required|string|max:255',
        'slug'  => 'required|string|max:255|unique:categories,slug,'.$this->segment(3),
    ];
}
```

Please note that `$this->segment(3)` refers to the id of the model being updated in the backend pages, it can be different in your application.